# ActiveMQ Artemis replication colocated not working

Tags: replication, activemq-artemis, colocation

I have a cluster of ActiveMQ Artemis and config them to replication colocated over network.

Here is two configs of them:

Broker1

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
           xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

<core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

  <name>10.1.1.130</name>


  <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

  <!-- this could be ASYNCIO, MAPPED, NIO
       ASYNCIO: Linux Libaio
       MAPPED: mmap files
       NIO: Plain Java Files
   -->
  <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>

  <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>

  <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>

  <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>

  <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

  <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

  <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

  <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

  <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>

  <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>

  <journal-buffer-timeout>23940000</journal-buffer-timeout>

  <journal-max-io>1</journal-max-io>

  <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
  <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

  <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
       that won't support flow control. -->
  <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

  <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
  <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

  <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

  <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

  <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>


 <!-- Clustering configuration -->
  <connectors>
     <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
     <!-- connector to the server2 -->
     <connector name="server2-connector">tcp://10.1.1.131:61616</connector>
  </connectors>
  <ha-policy>
     <replication>
        <colocated>
           <backup-request-retries>-1</backup-request-retries>
           <backup-request-retry-interval>2000</backup-request-retry-interval>
           <excludes>
              <connector-ref>server2-connector</connector-ref>
              <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
           </excludes>
           <max-backups>1</max-backups>
           <request-backup>true</request-backup>
           <master> 
           </master>
           <slave>
           </slave>
        </colocated>
     </replication>
  </ha-policy>
 <cluster-user>ACTIVEMQ.CLUSTER.ADMIN.USER</cluster-user>
 <cluster-password>123456</cluster-password>
 <cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
        <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
        <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
        <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
        <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
        <max-hops>1</max-hops>
        <static-connectors>
           <connector-ref>server2-connector</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
     </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>

  <acceptors>
     <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
     <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>

     <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
     <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>

     <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
     <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

     <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
     <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

     <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
     <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:4883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

  </acceptors>


  <security-settings>
     <security-setting match="#">
        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
        <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
        <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
     </security-setting>
  </security-settings>
```

Broker2:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
           xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

<core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">


  <name>10.1.1.131</name>


  <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

  <!-- this could be ASYNCIO, MAPPED, NIO
       ASYNCIO: Linux Libaio
       MAPPED: mmap files
       NIO: Plain Java Files
   -->
  <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>

  <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>

  <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>

  <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>

  <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

  <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

  <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

  <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

  <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>

  <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>

  <journal-buffer-timeout>23940000</journal-buffer-timeout>

  <journal-max-io>1</journal-max-io>

  <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
  <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

  <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
       that won't support flow control. -->
  <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

  <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
  <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

  <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

  <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

  <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>


 <!-- Clustering configuration -->
  <connectors>
     <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
     <!-- connector to the server1 -->
     <connector name="server1-connector">tcp://10.1.1.130:61616</connector>
  </connectors>
  <ha-policy>
     <replication>
        <colocated>
           <backup-request-retries>-1</backup-request-retries>
           <backup-request-retry-interval>2000</backup-request-retry-interval>
           <excludes>
              <connector-ref>server1-connector</connector-ref>
              <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
           </excludes>
           <max-backups>1</max-backups>
           <request-backup>true</request-backup>
           <master> 
           </master>
           <slave>
           </slave>
        </colocated>
     </replication>
  </ha-policy>
 <cluster-user>ACTIVEMQ.CLUSTER.ADMIN.USER</cluster-user>
 <cluster-password>123456</cluster-password>
 <cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
        <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
        <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
        <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
        <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
        <max-hops>1</max-hops>
        <static-connectors>
           <connector-ref>server1-connector</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
     </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>

  <acceptors>
     <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
     <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>

     <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
     <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>

     <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
     <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

     <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
     <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

     <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
     <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:4883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

  </acceptors>


  <security-settings>
     <security-setting match="#">
        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
        <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
        <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
     </security-setting>
  </security-settings>
```

Here is Srping Boot java Code to send message:

```
@Configuration
public class ArtemisProducerConfig extends BaseObject {
@Value("${artemis.broker-url}")
private String brokerUrl;

@Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory senderActiveMQConnectionFactory() {
    return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);
}

@Bean
public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory() {
    return new CachingConnectionFactory(senderActiveMQConnectionFactory());
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate template =  new JmsTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory());
    template.setExplicitQosEnabled(true);
    template.setDeliveryPersistent(true);
    return template;
}

}

jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("test.address::test.queue", inputData.getData(), new MessagePostProcessor() {

        @Override
        public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws JMSException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            message.setJMSCorrelationID(inputData.getCorrID());
            return message;
        }
    });
```

The Messsage is send to Broker1 success, I can view this on the site http://10.1.1.130:8161.
But on Broker2 no message available now.I understand that the Messages must be backed up to Broker2 to meet HA.

Can someone help me an example to configure Artemis to replication colocated over network?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ Artemis uses a active/passive scheme to achieve high-availability. In the replicated use-case therefore an active, "live" broker has a passive, "slave" broker to which it replicates messages. In a replicated & *colocated* configuration each JVM actually has 2 brokers (i.e. the two brokers are colocated in the same JVM). One broker is live and the other broker serves as a backup for another broker in the cluster. You won't "see" the messages on the slave until the live broker fails at which point the slave will activate and become the master.

To confirm that replication is happening as expected you can check the log files on the master and the slave. The slave will have something like this first:

```
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221109: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Backup Server version X.X.X [null] started, waiting live to fail before it gets active
```

Then the live will have something like this:

```
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221025: Replication: sending NIOSequentialFile /path/to/data/journal/activemq-data-2.amq (size=10,485,760) to replica.
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221025: Replication: sending NIOSequentialFile /path/to/data/bindings/activemq-bindings-3.bindings (size=1,048,576) to replica.
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221025: Replication: sending NIOSequentialFile /path/to/data/bindings/activemq-bindings-2.bindings (size=1,048,576) to replica.
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221024: Backup server ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=8d7477d0-1518-11ea-abd1-a0afbd82eaba is synchronized with live-server.
```

Then finally the slave will have:

```
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221031: backup announced
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser.
I can see the log file already have the log that you say: AMQ221031: backup announced...
But for my understand, I was config colocated that mean, The Broker1 is a live a backup of Broker2 and vice versa.
And, to ensure availability, all message need to replicate to all available Broker. 
Because, if message not replicate to other Broker, if the server dies suddenly
the message may be lost. This behavior not guarantee of availability.

Comment: In our Microservice system, maybe Producer send message to Broker1, and Consumer recieve from Broker2, and now Consumer may be never recieve message because message not replicate to Broker2.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comments. I hope that clarifies. I recommend you run some functional tests (i.e. set up a cluster with colocated HA and a handful of clients and kill one of the brokers) to see for yourself that replication is working as expected.

Comment: You mention a use-case where a producer sends a message to Broker1 and a consumer tries to receive the message from Broker2 but can't because replication allegedly isn't working. That's not what replication does. That's a use-case for message load balancing or redistribution which are both discussed in the [clustering documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/clusters.html).

Comment: I was insert follow line into broker.xml but no luck

<address-settings>
     <address-setting match="#">
     <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>
     </address-setting>
  </address-settings>

May I miss something else?

Comment: You're using `<message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>`. The documentation clearly states that `<message-load-balancing>` must be `ON_DEMAND` to enable redistribution.

Comment: Thank for your anwser, but the document said that: "If this is set to STRICT then each incoming message will be round robin'd even though the same queues on the other nodes of the cluster may have no consumers at all, or they may have consumers that have non matching message filters (selectors)"
And I was try with ON_DEMAND but no luck :(

Comment: I assumed since you set `<redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>` but indicated you still weren't seeing the behavior you expected that you expected redistribution to work and that you weren't specifically concerned with message load-balancing. This question started out asking about HA, but it seems now you're asking about clustering. Your use-case isn't clear so it's hard for me to advise at this point.

Comment: OK, possibly due to different interpretations of HA but What I want like this case https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2007?jql=text%20~%20"redistribution and it's seem cannot do it with artemis. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Message replication and redistribution are completely different concepts in ActiveMQ Artemis. The documentation is quite detailed about the support for redistribution based on filter/selectors. See the section titled ["Redistribution and filters (selectors)"](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/clusters.html).